# Maximum number of bytes that can be written to character driver in Linux

Tags: linux-device-driver

What is the max number of bytes that can be written to character driver in Linux?

Experimentally, I have found the number to be 32500 bytes. If I try to write more my device driver is killed.

I am following this tutorial on character drivers (https://appusajeev.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/writing-a-linux-character-device-driver/).

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  What is the data capacity of the device?  Or are you asking about a single write operation?  Obviously the driver you installed is at fault.  A device driver is trusted code, and should not compromise the security&integrity of the kernel.

Comment: If by data capacity you mean size of array that driver is given it is MAX_INT / 2 in my case. Yes I am asking about a single write operation.

Comment: Actually I asked about the capacity of the device, not the size of some array.  BTW on Linux an INT is typically 32 bits long.  So you are claiming that your buffer is 1 GB?  For a single write operation, the `write()` syscall uses a `length` variable of **size_t**, which is typically defined as a 32-bit unsigned integer.  But the driver example you cite uses an local **short integer**, and performs no range or bounds checking prior to the copy (like a proper kernel driver should).  The example code is flawed.  And your experimental result is bogus.